# Python: nested list and dictionary comparison

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm having trouble comparing a nested list with a dictionary of multiple values.
The dictionary and nested list are like so:

```
list = [[['a']], [['b']], [['c'], ['d']], [['e'], ['f'], ['g']]]

dict = {'adv0' : ('a', 'b'), 'adv1' : ('f', 'c'), 'adv2' : ('d', 'e', 'q')}
```

I want to create an array where each sublist ('a', 'b', 'c & d', 'e & f & g') is compared to each value and if any item in the sublist is a member of that value it creates a 0 entry, otherwise it creates a 1 entry.

[0, 1, 1] since 'a' is only in adv0, [0, 1, 1] since 'b' is only in adv0, [1, 0, 0] since adv1 and adv2 contain 'c' or 'd', [1, 0, 0] since adv1 and adv2 contain one of 'e', 'f' or 'g'. Hence we get the array [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0].

The following code is my horrible attempt at a solution which doesn't work:

```
l = []
for sublist in list:
      for items in sublist:
        for x in items:
          for key in dict:
            if x in dict[key]:
              l.extend('0')
            elif x not in dict[key]:
              l.extend('1')
print l
```

Comment: Note that dictionaries are not ordered. It sounds like you want the resulting list ordered by a natural sort on the dict keys -- but it would be good to mention that explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is dictionaries are unordered, so you may not iterate through the keys as you expect.  use an `OrderedDict` or iterate specifically through the keys you want.  This works:

```
L = [[['a']], [['b']], [['c'], ['d']], [['e'], ['f'], ['g']]]
D = {'adv0' : ('a', 'b'), 'adv1' : ('f', 'c'), 'adv2' : ('d', 'e', 'q')}

l = []
for sublist in L:
    for key in ('adv0','adv1','adv2'):
        if any(item[0] in D[key] for item in sublist):
            l.append(0) # changed to give explicit output you listed.
        else:
            l.append(1) # ditto
print l
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: (I renamed the input to lst and dct to avoid conflicting with the built-in `list` and `dict` objects)

```
[0 if any(v[0] in dct[k] for v in sublst) else 1 
   for sublst in lst 
     for k in sorted(dct.keys())]
```

That was fun. *(But, sadly, 3 minutes too late...)*

Comment: I was quite surprised how similar out solutions were.